# Firebase Realtime Database Security, only read messages from last 10 minutes using timestamp not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've seen a few posts and documentation on achieving this, but I can't get it to work.

I'm saving a timestamp to each chat message with `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

If I add the security rule found in the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) (pasted below) it won't return any messages at all. Whenever I remove the snippet checking the timestamp, all messages return as expected.

`".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",`

Here's my security rules for all my documents (see the `.read` under `chat/` for the specific rule I'm wondering about)

```
  "rules": {
    "online": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && auth.token.email_verified == true"
      }
    },
    "chat": {
      ".indexOn": ["timestamp"],
      // signed in and message was sent in last 10 min
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",
      // signed in, your user id, and authed thru ig
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('iga').val() == true",
      "$uid": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['username', 'timestamp', 'text', 'user_id'])",
        "timestamp": { 
          ".validate": "newData.val() <= now"
        },
        "text": { 
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length <= 280"
        },
        "user_id": {
          ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
        "$uid": {
        // only read your user
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        // only admin can write
        ".write": "false",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['iga'])",
      }
    },
    "video_src": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid === 'Fcbp0p6Gd3Q5baljAV0rGWBqSR22'"
    },
    "captions": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid === '2HgVzfosZqgK0LINUeYWKF1Bxyi2'",
      "$uid":{
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length <= 140"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how I'm querying for the chat data:

```
   const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
   return this.chatRef
      .orderByChild('timestamp')
      .startAt(timestamp)
      .on('child_added', 
        snapshot => callback(this.parseMessage(snapshot))
      )
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't use pictures of code and text.  It's better to copy the text directly into the question and format it so that it's easy to read.  The editor has ways for indicating which text is code or quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters):

> **Rules Are Not Filters**
>
> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every affected child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail completely.

The examples there demonstrate that if you make a query that *could* return restricted data, the entire query fails even if all the data that is actually present would be allowed.

While Realtime Database and Firestore are different products, they behave the same in this respect and I think the Firestore documentation is much clearer on this concept so I'll leave in the paragraph from Firestore's documentation.

> Cloud Firestore security rules evaluate each query against its potential result and fails the request if it could return a document that the client does not have permission to read. Queries must follow the constraints set by your security rules.

Make sure that your query is only asking for records that are allowed. Asking for records that are out of bounds will fail the entire request, hence why you get no messages when the rule is in place.

Comment: Thanks, but this is from the `Cloud Firestore` documentation, not the `Realtime Database` documentation. Are you sure this applies to the realtime database?

Comment: See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) to view the Realtime Database docs

Comment: My apologies. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) is a section stating the same thing from the realtime database docs. I'll update my answer to match.

Comment: Thanks Elan ! I updated my answer to show how i'm querying for the data

Comment: Check the [Query-based Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules) section under the one I linked for the answer to your edit

Comment: updated to add query based rules and still not getting anything. Note that I'm never getting permission denied errors, but never getting any messages.